# Error while destroy Ember Data record

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have encounterd an error while deleting an Ember data record and I could not figure out why,

```
Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <card:32> while in state root.deleted.inFlight. 
Error
```

The code below is where the error get triggered,

```
    deleteBtnClicked() {
        const controller = this.controllerFor('browse/index');
        let selectedCards = controller.getSelectedCard();
        selectedCards = selectedCards.map((card) => {
            return parseInt(Ember.get(card, 'id'));
        });

        selectedCards.forEach((id) => {
            this.store.find('card', id)
                .then((card) => {
                    card.destroyRecord();
                });
        });
    }
```

Turns out the records have been deleted successfuly but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find is private method](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.11.0/addon/-private/system/store.js#L441) so please don't use it. Instead you can use [`findAll`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findAll) and [`findRecord`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord)

```
deleteBtnClicked() {
    const controller = this.controllerFor('browse/index');
    let selectedCards = controller.getSelectedCard();
    //if selectedCards itself is RecordArray you can easily iterate using forEach and destroyRecord. no need of findRecord.
    selectedCards = selectedCards.map((card) => {
        return parseInt(Ember.get(card, 'id'));
    });
    //I added reload: true this will ensure promise will be resolved only after adapters returns the data.
    selectedCards.forEach((id) => {
        this.store.findRecord('card', id, { reload: true })
            .then((card) => {
                card.destroyRecord();
            });
    });
}
```